# Probability of positive definiteness of a random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, probability-distributions, random-matrices, positivity

Given an $n \times n$ symmetric random matrix whose entries have distribution $N(0,1)$, how to calculate the probability of positive definiteness of this matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following papers are closely related to what you are looking for:

- [How many eigenvalues of a Gaussian random matrix are positive?](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.83.041105) (2011)
- [Index Distribution of Gaussian Random Matrices](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.220603) (2009)

They compute the probability that all eigenvalues of a random matrix are positive.